# Can't Access Port number 80

Tags: apache, apache2, firewall, iptables

I added to my Input-Chain a rule for accepting port 80 with:

```
iptables -I INPUT 10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

So my iptable looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.0.0/16          anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.0.0/16          anywhere             tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.0.0/16          anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

But I still cannot access my website with:

> `http://mywebsite.de`

In access.log I see following requests:

```
88.217.227.203 - - [20/May/2022:09:28:18 +0200] "-" 408 4743 "-" "-"
88.217.227.203 - - [20/May/2022:09:36:02 +0200] "-" 408 4743 "-" "-"
88.217.227.203 - - [20/May/2022:09:36:45 +0200] "-" 408 4743 "-" "-"
```

May be some guessings why it does not work?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I have figuried it out myself:
I a line for listeting on port 80 in port.conf in /etc/apache2 was commented out

> #Listen 80

Changed it to

> Listen 80